# Open file with generator - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, glob

I want to open a file from a directory with a python generator - it's a csv-file and in the dir are about 8 csv-files. Yes I know, I also could use the csv-lib, but I wonder if I could do it without the lib.

Here's my code so far:

```
vz = glob.glob("home/user/*csv")

data = [ open(i, 'r') for i in vz if "some_file_name" in i ]
```

After that I get:

```
print data

==> [<open file '/home/user/some_file_name.csv', mode 'r' at 0x1eb78a0>]

for i in data.readlines():
    print i

==> 'list' object has no attribute 'readlines'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `glob` to find your file, rather than naming it directly? Why not just `open("home/user/some_file_name.csv", "r")`? Also, there's rarely a need to call `readlines` on a file, since they're already iterable. Just loop on the file object directly.

Comment: There is a reason: I use `argv` to run the script with two arguments. With these arguments I search for the right files. It's something like `python script.py arg1 arg2` and the file I'm searchin for is named `filename_arg1_arg2`, so I do `if "filename_%s_%s" % (arg1, arg2) in vz: ...`..

Comment: Do you expect to get more than one match, ever? Or, do you need to support non-exact matches (e.g. with extra characters)? If you're really only looking for the single file named `"filename_arg1_arg2.csv"` (where `arg1` and `arg2` are your command line arguments), just use `open("filename_{}_{}.csv".format(arg1, arg2))` or the similar `%s` code you're already using in your test. There's no need to glob and loop over all the CSV files if you know the whole name. Dealing with just a single file will probably fix the issue you're having (which the answer below probably has correctly described).

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I was searching for. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `data` is a list with one element, which is the file object you are trying to read. This should work:

```
for i in data[0].readlines():
    print i
```